# Where to store media file of Django on production?

Tags: django, heroku, django-storage, python-django-storages, supabase

So I am learning Django. And I have made some websites with it. Now I am hosting those to Heroku. I am using free Dyno on `Heroku`. Also, I am using `supabase.io` database instead of Heroku's because `supabase` gives more space for the database on the free tier. Now the problem I am facing is with the media files. I can not access them on `Heroku` since I don't have any place to store them.

I have seen some addons on `Heroku` for the file storage but to use those I need to provide my credit card information, which I do not have.

But I have seen an object storage option on `supabase.io`. It gives 1 GB free storage which is more than enough for me now. But I don't know how can I use it with my Django application. That is why I am looking for help. Also if there are any free alternatives to store my media file without credit card information, please feel free to guide me. Since I do not own any card.

Answer (score 3):

There is a community-supported Python library for Supabase that has support for Supabase Storage, which you can try:

https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py

see the storage code here:

https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/tree/develop/supabase/lib/storage

Comment: I read the doc and after connected, I can't upload anything in the Supabase storage bucket.
```url=  "XXXXX"
key = "XXXXXXXXX
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
my_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__")) + "/file.jpg"
storage.upload(path=supabase.storage_url, file=my_file)```
I doesn't work and don't print any error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a user of the Python library, but you can post your issue here in the Github repository:  https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/issues, or join our Discord to interact with other Supabase Python developers: https://discord.supabase.io/

Comment: Hey!

Thanks for the question! I'm one of the maintainers of the Supabase Python client library. I'm currently working on an integration with django-storages: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/1099 . I'll publish a blog post once done but please you should be able  to use the client lib that Mark has mentioned for now.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be an old question, but for future reference, you could probably try out `django-cloudinary-storage`. You can take a look at this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72673627/15978450).