# How and Where to put 10GB of content for a website?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I am making a Django website for our college's debating society. They have approx. 30GB worth of video content. Where should I store it in Database (PostgreSQL is being used) during development and when in production. Does it cost to have a certain amount of GB content when in production?
If there is another way for the same, please feel free to share that as well!

Comment: store them on youtube but not public upload to youtube as accessible with link

Comment: Then use iFrame for displaying that video content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you're looking to have some storage area online to save your project's content. If I'm correct, then I'd suggest using [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/pricing) since they have a free tier that gives users up to 25GB (*they'll say 25 credits*) monthly the last time I checked. Plus, you don't have to sign up with a credit card like most of the top competitors out there.

What's also good about them is that you can use it as Django's default storage area by doing an `install` and configuring it in your `settings.py` file. To help you set up, you can visit [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration).

Additionally, you can look at some other competitors and choose based on your liking. There's a page on [SaaSworthy](https://www.saasworthy.com/product/cloudinary/pricing) you could check out when you have the time.